# Calling methods of an object instantiated in another class

Tags: java, object, user-interface

Alright guys, I've managed to totally confuse myself trying to build a GUI for a program I had working well in text form.

Essentially the program tracks inventory. Product name, number, cost, quantity, etc. Initially I simply had a class 'Items' which covered all the getters and setters. I would then use scanners etc to prompt a text based menu that you would input very systematically each element. I understand how that all worked well because i could instantiate an array of Items that stored all of the Item objects that i could then manipulate. All of that however occurred in main().

Now I've additionally created an Inventory class that handles the majority of what my main() and been handling before. I want to create one "Inventory" object that i would then be able to use throughout my program, primarily within my ActionListeners. I.E. inventory.displayText(position); Unfortunately, because my GUI is a separate class from my main()--where I'm instantiating the Inventory class--I don't have a local variable "inventory" so i get an error.

This seems like it should be absurdly simple, but my brain just doesn't seem to be wrapping around it.

here's the idea:

```
public class Items{

     all item variables
     setters and getters()

  }
```

---

```
 public class Inventory{

     Items[] arrayOfItems = new Items[10]

     displayItem(int placement){
          ...code to display items

     }

  }
```

---

```
 public class GUI extends JFrame{

       public GUI(){
               ...general gui layout...
               forwardButton = new JButton("Forward");

         }


  private class eventHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            int placement = 1;


            if (event.getSource()==forwardButton){

                if (placement < 10){
                    placement++;
                    inv.displayItem(placement);   //this is where the problem is and where I
                }                                  //have lost myself. inv doesnt exist here.
                                                   //so i cant call upon the object from here.
```

---

```
public class Company{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Open GUI
    GUI mainGUI = new GUI();
    mainGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainGUI.setSize(1000,1000);
    mainGUI.setVisible(true);

    //initialize inventory object
    Inventory inv = new Inventory();

    }

}
```

I'm almost 100% certain its something super fundamental but I'm just not gettin it. If you guys could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You get an error. Which error ?

Comment: in my GUI class i get an error that "inv.displayItem(placement)" doesnt work because "inv" isnt a recognized local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite correct that you have no access to your inventory object in `eventHandler`, but it's fairly easy to fix that.  `eventHandler` is an inner class of `GUI`.  It turns out that in Java, non-static inner classes have access to members of the enclosing class (see [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more information).  This means that anything that you declare in `GUI` will be visible in `eventHandler`.

What you need to do is create a member of `GUI` of type `Inventory`, and pass your `inv` instance in when you create the `GUI`.  At this point your `eventHandler` will be able to see it.

Your `GUI` constructor will look like this...

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private Inventory inv;

    public GUI(Inventory inv) {
        this.inv = inv;
        // other stuff
    }
    // etc
```

...and then in your `main()` method, you can pass a reference to `inv` to the constructor like so:

```
public class Company{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //initialize inventory object
        Inventory inv = new Inventory();

        //Open GUI
        GUI mainGUI = new GUI(inv);
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: AHA!!! Thank you!! This is exactly what I needed. And so simple! I knew it would be....

Comment: Now, I think I've run into another problem. Does this method of passing the inv object through the constructor allow me to edit the SAME object? Because it seems like its creating a new inv within that class that i would then have to pass back to my mainGUI in order to use these changes later.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field and a setter in your GUI class for `Inventory`.
Then, in your `main` after instantiating your inventory, you can just call `mainGUI.setInv(inv)` and your GUI Class has access to the inventory.

Comment: I'm not sure i totally follow. Do you mean within GUI create a new Inventory object? Then use a getInv() method within main() and call it within GUI to populate the new inventory object?

Comment: Not a new object, but a field, like this: `private Inventory inv;`. Then inside `GUI` a `setInv(Inventory inv) {this.inv = inv;}`. Then you should be all set. Or you could do the approach from the other answers and create a constructor where you pass the `Inventory` object from your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would just be to pass the inventory into the GUI constructor:

```
 private Inventory inventory;

 public GUI(Inventory inv){

      this.inventory = inv;

      ...general gui layout...
      forwardButton = new JButton("Forward");

 }
```

Then change the instantiation of the GUI to pass the inventory in:

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory();
GUI mainGUI = new GUI(inv);
```

While this approach should get you off the ground, you may want to read up on the Model-View-Controller pattern and how to implement it in [Java Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html).

MVC divides the application into:

- The Model, or the underlying data of the application (your inventory
  object)
- The View, or an interface to that data (your GUI)
- The Controller, or an entity that coordinates changes between the View and the Model (You would need to redesign a bit to have a clear-cut Controller)

Comment: The other guy beat you to it, but this is exactly what im looking for, thank you!  Ill also be checking into the Model-View-Controller pattern. Thanks for the tip